# utf-8-unix versus utf-8-dos in Emacs on Windows. Which is more advantageous and why?

Tags: utf-8

I run Emacs in msys2 on Windows. I have set my system environment to `utf-8` using this command in my `.bashrc`: `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. This has resulted in the coding being set to `utf-8-dos` without the need to make any changes to my init.el. Does `utf-8-dos` offer advantages over `utf-8-unix` if one is running Emacs on Windows in msys2?

Comment: Instead of asking which is better, ask for advantages of each. Otherwise, the question encourages opinion-based answers.

Comment: If you don't get the answer you want, just use `utf-8`.

Comment: Do you mean by setting it explicitly in dot emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `utf-8-unix` and `utf-8-dos` are the characters signaling a newline.
In unix this is the line feed or `LF` character whereas in dos a newline is signaled by a carriage return character or short `CR`, followed by a line feed.
So when editing files in `utf-8-unix` when you enter a newline the character `LF` is added to the buffer. In `utf-8-dos` entering a newline adds the two characters `CR LF` to the buffer.
`CR` and `LF` here are just representations of those characters.
They are not literally the letters C and R or L and F written out.
A table listing the different representations can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation)

Which mode is better for you depends on where else you will be using the files you write.
If they are consumed by Windows programs the dos newline encoding will be more compatible.
However, I found most other editors on Windows being able to handle unix newline encoding as well.
Emacs shows the `CR` characters as `^M` if using `utf-8-unix` encoding.
So if you write these files for a mostly Linux audience maybe consider using the unix style newline encodings for less visual clutter.

If you look at [the emacs manual page for coding system basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-System-Basics.html) you can find that there is a third option.
*Variant coding systems* as `utf-8-unix` and `utf-8-dos` are so specfiy the newline characters. *Base coding systems* however, leave the newline characters unspecified and should adapt to the file you are using. In this case that would be just `utf-8`.

I would use `utf-8-dos` if you are mostly using these files on Windows and `utf-8-unix` if you are creating files for a repository that is used by mostly Linux users.
In the end I think it does not matter too much which one you choose.
Most programs know how to handle both and it is trivial to convert if you ever need to. [Specifying a Coding System for File Text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Coding.html) in the manual lists the commands you can use for this.